# Check for video file integrity for - bulk

Tags: video

Have more then 1000 mxf files.
Is there a software that can bulk check all of them for any kind of corruption/integrity ?
I found several answers on stackexchange but all include Linux commands that I am not sure how to use since I am on win10.
Any sort of user friendly software would be great, like handbrake or media encoder ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several widely adopted file-based QC systems on the market. They include:

- [Interra Baton](http://www.interrasystems.com/file-based-qc.php)
- [Telestream (formerly Tektronix) Aurora](http://www.telestream.net/vidchecker/overview.htm#aurora)
- [Telestream Vidchecker](http://www.telestream.net/vidchecker/overview.htm)
- [Venera Pulsar](http://www.veneratech.com/pulsar-automated-file-qc)

Note that as of NAB NY 2019, Telestream had not announced plans for what will happen with Vidchecker and Aurora after the Tektronix acquisition.

Comment: Thx! These all seem as tools for large broadcasters, and I guess the price is heavy (none are available to see online).

Comment: They are not only used by large broadcasters. I know of many post houses that use one of the systems I listed or similar alternatives. Feel free to update the question with what your budget is.

Comment: This is 1 or 2 times a year process, budget under 100$